# Object/Instance issue?

Tags: java, oop, object, instance, instances

so this is a rather complicated problem for me but I will try to explain best I can -

I have a class called **Survey** with an:

```
ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

The list is where I store all the questions belonging to a survey. 
I am trying to iterate over this list and display these questions.

Here is the tricky part. I have a **Main** class that uses an instance of **Survey** to call it's menu methods, and an instance of **Survey** in a **Question** class where the current question is being added to the ArrayList.

When I print out:

```
survey.questions.size()
```

in my **Questions** class, after adding one question I get "1".

However when I print out the size in my **Survey** class, I got "0".

I believe the issue is because Main is using a separate instance of **Survey** to iterate over the question list than the instance in which I'm adding the questions, in my **Question** class.

I will try to clear any confusion!

---

```
public class Survey {

public ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();

// Iterate over questions List
public void displayQuestions() {
    int numberCount = 1;
    int optionCount = 1;

     System.out.println(questions.size()); // PRINTS 0

    for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("Question" + numberCount + ") ");
        System.out.println(questions.get(i).prompt);

        for(int j = 0; j < questions.get(i).options.size(); j++) {
            System.out.print(optionCount + ". ");
            System.out.println(questions.get(i).options.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Main {

    private static Survey survey = new Survey();
    // After selecting "Display Survey" menu option
    survey.displayQuestions();
```

---

```
public class Question {

    protected Survey survey = new Survey();
    // After finishing making the question
    survey.questions.add(this);
    System.out.println(survey.questions.size()); // PRINTS 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got more than one Survey instance, and one has one question added to it, while the other in main has no questions. That's it.

Solution: use only one instance of Survey, and pass it if needed to where it is needed, but don't create a new instance and expect it to hold the same state as other instances because that's not how Java works. Note that Question should most definitely **not** create an instance of Survey. It can add itself to an existing instance, but it makes no sense for it to create an instance de novo.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> This is what I thought! I'm very amateur and im trying to stick to good design. Both `survey.displayQuestions()` and `survey.questions.add(this)` need survey objects to call those methods but I have them in separate classes. I'm not sure how to only use one.

My own inclination is to have the Question class be ignorant of Survey, in other words, it should not hold a Survey instance nor call any of its methods, since it really doesn't need to know about survey, and your goal in coding OOP programs is to minimize connections. Instead whatever class that creates Question instances, have *that* place the Question into the Survey object.

Comment: This is what I thought! I'm very amateur and im trying to stick to good design. Both `survey.displayQuestions()` and `survey.questions.add(this)` need survey objects to call those methods but I have them in separate classes. I'm not sure how to only use one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it so much! I'm going to try and find a way to do what you said, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a new class that returns a static instance of questions. That way both main and the question class can ask for a copy of the static list.

In the new class, check to see if the instance is null, if null then new up the static instance and then return it. Depending on the complexity of the application you might want to considering adding locking to avoid threat safe issues.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to down-vote this answer. The last thing that we want to recommend is for the OP to create static instances when none are needed. If thread safety is an issue (and we have absolutely no indication of this) then there are much better ways of solving this than throwing the baby out with the bath water.

Comment: He's was already creating a static instance and if he needs it to hang around between being main and question classes is seems perfectly reasonable to store it off in as a static list. Granted we don't know enough about the application to make that decision.